# Foundation contact form js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation, uglifyjs

I have my contact form ready to go but for some reason when i gulp it with uglify it returns an error and won't minify. My javascript seems correct and it will uglify when I remove the ajax call but with the ajax call it breaks. Any insight? Here's my js:

```
$('.contact-form').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {
        var name = $(".contact-form input#name").val();
        var email = $(".contact-form input#email").val();
        var message = $(".contact-form textarea#message").val;
        // Data for response
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + 
            '& email =' + email + 
            '& message =' + message;
        //Begin Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/mail.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('.contact-form').html("<div id ='success'></div>");
                    $('#success').html("<h2>Thanks!</h2>")
                            .append("<p>Dear" + name + "!, I look forward to working with you.</p>")
                            .hide()
                            .fadeIn(1500);
                            },
        }); //ajax call
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JsLint throws error on this code. Removing the trailing comma seems to clear it up:

```
.fadeIn(1500);
}, /* <-- remove this comma */
```